# JavaScript: detect page is scrolling on scroll-behavior: smooth and deprecate scroll event in this case

Tags: javascript, html

I have a scroll event and I have links in HTML which smoothly scroll page content via `scroll-behavior: smooth`. And I need my scroll event execute ONLY if there is no scroll by link click.

Here is a small example:

```js
function scrollHandler() {
  console.log("scroll");
}

const throttledScrollHandler = throttle(scrollHandler, 200);

window.addEventListener("scroll", throttledScrollHandler);
window.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  if (e.target.closest("a")) {
    // I can kill this event listener onclick, but when could I disable it?
    //window.removeEventListener('scroll', scrollHandler)
    console.log("clicked");
  }
});

function throttle(callback, delay) {
  let timer = null;

  return function throttledFunc(...args) {
    if (timer) {
      return;
    }

    timer = setTimeout(() => {
      callback(...args);

      if (timer) {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = null;
      }
    }, delay);
  };
}
```

```css
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

body {
  font-family: Arial;
}

section {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 150vh;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: #fff;
}

section:nth-of-type(1) {
  background-color: black;
}

section:nth-of-type(2) {
  background-color: grey;
}

section:nth-of-type(3) {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./src/styles.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#section1">Section 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#section2">Section 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#section3">Section 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

    <section id="section1">Section 1</section>
    <section id="section2">Section 2</section>
    <section id="section3">Section 3</section>
  </body>
</html>
```

I need to do something to prevent here `scroll` mark in console if I click a link, but stay if I simply scroll.

Here is a codesandbox [with this example](https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-stitch-vqrgqt)

Answer (score 1):

You might need to use the `wheel` event instead of the `scroll` event. Here are the changes you can make to your javascript to get the desired effect.

```
function scrollHandler() {
  console.log("scroll");
}

const throttledScrollHandler = throttle(scrollHandler, 200);

window.addEventListener("wheel", throttledScrollHandler ); 

window.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  if (e.target.closest("a")) {
  
    console.log("clicked")
   
  }
});



function throttle(callback, delay) {
  let timer = null;

  return function throttledFunc(...args) {
    if (timer) {
      return;
    }

    timer = setTimeout(() => {
      callback(...args);

      if (timer) {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = null;
      }
    }, delay);
  };
}
``
```

Comment: please note that this won't work if the user uses scrollbars to scroll. good luck!